# PHP can't call function in script in WHILE LOOP

Tags: php

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "optimax2u") or die("Could not connect database");
$r = mysqli_query($link, "select * from careers");
$index = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
    echo "<button onclick='myFunction('".$index++."')' class='w3-button w3-block w3-left-align'>".$row['title']."</button>"; /* the button can't call function at script*/
    echo "<div id='".$index++."' class='w3-hide w3-container'>";
    $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM careerdetails WHERE careerTitle='".$row['title']."'");
    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo '<ul>';
        echo '<li>';
        echo ''.$row1['qualifications'].'';
        echo '</li>';
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
</div>
<script>
    function myFunction(id) {
        alert(id);
        var x = document.getElementById(id);
        if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
            x.className += " w3-show";
        } else { 
            x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the single quotes you have around the (id) `$index++`

```
  echo "<button onclick='myFunction(" .$index++.")' 
        class='w3-button w3-block w3-left-align'>".$row['title']."</button>";
```

Comment: Maybe you should also explain, why removing them solves the problem - in general it isn't the best advice to remove quotes from an string

Comment: the quote added  by the op are wrong and not  build the properr function signature.. the value passed  is passed  as a string and not as an id.. you can easly see the result in the html code generated pressing ctrl+U